# How to fix button transforming to custom button with border when page open?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, atom-editor

My goal was that when I hover to the button the background color fade in but when my mouse move out of the button, I want the background color to fade out.
So I did that by inserting the transition property in the CSS for both button and button:hover in order for it to fade in and out. I also have the same button on my drop down menu which creates the same effect. By the way, I do this on Atom and it seems to not have a problem in Atom's Preview Browser Package.

I tried changing position, transition effect but none of it works. Any ideas?

This is what happens to the button when I open/refresh the webpage:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYTvB.gif

HTML:

```
<button onclick="location.href='Contact.html';" type="button">Book an Appointment <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    cursor: pointer;
    background:none;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px 24px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 52%;
    left: 42%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Gotham";
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

button:hover {
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
}
```

I expect the background color of the button to fade in & out when my mouse hovers without any animation when the webpage is opened for the first time or refreshed.

Comment: Please don't remove content just because an issue was solved... This question is less useful not just because of your edit but because you removed your comments.

Answer (score 0):

added some changes in your css

```
<button onclick="location.href='Contact.html';" type="button">Book an Appointment <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>

button {
    cursor: pointer;
    background:none;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px 24px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Gotham";
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: all 1s;
}

button:hover {
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
}
```

```css
button {
    cursor: pointer;
    background:none;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px 24px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Gotham";
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: all 1s;
}

button:hover {
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="location.href='Contact.html';" type="button">Book an Appointment <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, Your code doesn't have any problem

```css
button {
    cursor: pointer;
    background:none;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px 24px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Gotham";
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.with{  
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.with:hover {
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
  background: rgba(110, 120, 90, 0.5);
}


.without:hover {
  background: rgba(110, 120, 90, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<button class="with" onclick="location.href='Contact.html';" type="button" >With Animation<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>

<button class="without" onclick="location.href='Contact.html';" type="button" >Without Animation<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
```

If you don't need animation just drop `transition` property from `css`

Comment: Are you using `animate.css` in your project? Because I don't have any issue in my `chrome` like you've mentioned, It doesn't animate in load time.

Comment: Try out other browsers too, its actually not a problem but if client wants to be pixel perfect then it seems to be a problem. Anyway do a simple page with no css and test it in chrome

Comment: Do one more thing, create a new `index.html` file and put your `button` codes there and test it in `chrome`. It it remains the same, then you have to think about chrome. And if not then some other `css` or `js` library is doing that animation for you

Comment: So you are saying that no external or internal `css` reference, no `js` references, you are still facing the same problem? well then it is with the browser. But do one thing, `transition : 0.5s ease-out` and refresh again

Comment: Sorry buddy, I've tried with a simple button in a html page and still not getting that issue. My chrome version is `Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Comment: I was told you to do this in a single page detached from your project, just like this one

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvEvX.png

Comment: Inspecting other pages doesn't affect chrome, however every time you change any `css` or `js` of your project its safe to reload your page by `ctrl+F5`, It refreshes browser cache and load new `js` and `css`

Comment: That's what I'm talking after second comment! :) Anyway, now you know what's wrong.

Comment: That's not to solution! You've imported a `library` (it can be `css` or 'js') which has doing that animation for you. You've to identify that by yourself and decide whether you want to use it or not. Or how you want to use it. And always `style` an element by `class` not with attribute (e.g give `button` a class and then write `css` for that instead of direct css for `button`). I hope that I've made myself clear